# fitsSystemWindows counterpart in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a transparent status/navigation bars, and when I place a compose element with default layout(top/left), it's placed under the status bar. In xml I use `fitsSystemWindows` to fix this, how can I get same effect in jetpack compose?

Comment: Have a look at this library https://chrisbanes.github.io/accompanist/insets/

Comment: Looks like it should do exactly what I need. But I couldn't get it to work. I call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`, and wrap my view with `ProvideWindowInsets`, but it the view is still there - what am I missing?

Comment: Or should I then use one of the modifiers to all the views I need to inset?

Comment: You have to use the modifier that fits your needs, e.g. Modifier.systemBarsPadding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, In Activity I have :

```
  WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
  setContent {
      JetpackComposePlaygroundTheme {
         val controller = rememberAndroidSystemUiController()
         CompositionLocalProvider(LocalSystemUiController provides controller) {
            ProvideWindowInsets {
                  ComposeAppPlayground()
            }
         }
      }
  }
```

Then In compose app playground I have something like this:

```
  Surface {

            var topAppBarSize by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
            val contentPaddings = LocalWindowInsets.current.systemBars.toPaddingValues(
                top = false,
                additionalTop = with(LocalDensity.current) { topAppBarSize.toDp() }
            )

            Column(modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding().padding(top = contentPaddings.calculateTopPadding())) {
               // content can go here forexample...
               // if you want the content go below status bar 
               //   you can remove the top padding for column 
            }

            InsetAwareTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(stringResource(R.string.home)) },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface.copy(alpha = 0.9f),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .onSizeChanged { topAppBarSize = it.height }
            )
        }
    }
```

Also the InsetAwareTopAppBar I found from guids mentioned in https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/

```
@Composable
fun InsetAwareTopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = 4.dp
) {
    Surface(
        color = backgroundColor,
        elevation = elevation,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = title,
            navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
            actions = actions,
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            contentColor = contentColor,
            elevation = 0.dp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .statusBarsPadding()
                .navigationBarsPadding(bottom = false)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be statusBars instead of systemBars.